# BigCommerce - Force Mobile Template

Tags: javascript, bigcommerce

I am using Blueprint theme on BigCommerce. My template is pretty customized and the design team that worked on this did not have responsive design in mind. However, there is a mobile template option that we have active. Although this is good, it's strictly for mobile devices.

I was wondering if there is anyway to trigger this template to become active when the window resizes. I've searched around to try and find the JS files that trigger the store to look at the "mobile_template" files over than the regular template, but I cannot find it.

Is there anyway to force this? I would re-do the site but it would be reinventing the wheel when I can simply change the layout to the mobile version which works perfectly.

Comment: [css media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) may be helpful.

Comment: @Hodrobond ah yes, I am aware of such. As I said it's not a daunting task to do this but it's excessive work, and slightly redundant, if I can just change the conditions of the mobile template being used from mobile to window-resize or something similar to that.

Answer (score 1):

The "mobile device" detection that routes to the mobile template is based on the user agent of the requesting device. If the user agent is detected to be a phone or tablet (and based on your settings in the store) BC will serve up the alternate template. Unfortunately I'm not aware of a way to toggle that dynamically with JS on page resize, and it would involve a full page reload anyways.